# Ruby on Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl Chapter 8 failing last test under 8.31 listing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, tdd, ruby-on-rails-5

When trying to make a test in  https://www.railstutorial.org/book/basic_login#code-user_logout_test using 8.31 listing:

```
 require 'test_helper'

class UsersLoginTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  .
  .
  .
  test "login with valid information followed by logout" do
    get login_path
    post login_path, params: { session: { email:    @user.email,
                                          password: 'password' } }
    assert is_logged_in?
    assert_redirected_to @user
    follow_redirect!
    assert_template 'users/show'
    assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path, count: 0
    assert_select "a[href=?]", logout_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", user_path(@user)
    delete logout_path
    assert_not is_logged_in?
    assert_redirected_to root_url
    follow_redirect!
    assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", logout_path,      count: 0
    assert_select "a[href=?]", user_path(@user), count: 0
  end
end
```

I am getting a failure:

```
FAIL["test_login_with_valid_information_followed_by_logout", UsersLoginTest, 1.7831762819550931]
 test_login_with_valid_information_followed_by_logout#UsersLoginTest (1.78s)
        Expected at least 1 element matching "a[href="/login"]", found 0..
        Expected 0 to be >= 1.
        test/integration/users_login_test.rb:35:in `block in <class:UsersLoginTest>'
```

Maybe someone know where is a problem? I double check the chapter, seems that everything is done as in tutorial said.

Much obliged,

Comment: It seems like your homepage doesn't have an link to `/login`

Comment: Please put your `routes.rb`, `sessions_controller.rb`, `_header.html.erb` and your `application.html.erb` in the question... I'm guessing it's an issue in either of these.

Comment: Seems mistake was in `_header.html.erb`. I was missing `login_path` in `<li><%= link_to "Log in", login_path %></li>`. Thank you everyone for replies and help, case solved)